# Trocar Conteudo de uma div de volta ao original

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma div que alarga depois de o utilizador clicar num link (+).
Vou buscar o conteudo a um ficheiro local que contem paragrafos a imprimir.
Neste paragrafos consiste um link (-) que devolvia a div original.
Para isto tou a usar o seguinte script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.more').click(function(){
            $('#'+$(this).attr('href')).load('content-box_en.phtml #' + $(this).attr('href')+'-p');
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.reset').click(function(){
            $('#'+$(this).attr('href')).load('reset_en.phtml #' + $(this).attr('href')+'-p');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

O link (+) tem a class "more", e o (-) a class "reset".
O primeiro link funciona exatamente como eu queria, enquanto o segundo nao reconhece a class do link (-)(não sei se é por causa deste vir de um ficheiro externo e como a pagina nao da refresh quando imprime..) e apenas tenta dar redirect para href que resulta em erro.
Não tou muito dentro de JS e qualquer ajuda era apreciada!

**UPDATED**
HTML:

```
<

!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="trans-bar" style="background-image: url('img/transparencia.png');">
            <div class="trans-center">
                <center><img src="img/logo-sysdevmobilecomputing.png" style="width: 300px; height: 40px"></center>
            </div>
            <div class="trans-right">
                <div class="trans-lang">
                    <a class="trans-link" href="index_en.html" style="color: whitesmoke;">EN</a><strong> | </strong><a class="trans-link" href="index.html" >PT</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <section class="section-white">
            <div class="container">
                <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <!-- Indicators -->
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>
                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <img src="img/banner-kalipso.png" alt="...">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="img/banner-mss.jpg" alt="...">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="img/banner-apps.jpg" alt="...">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div id="header-box">
            <p>Kalipso is a fast and powerful mobile application generator for Microsoft OS (Mobile, CE, Seven, 8 PRO and Windows 10) and Android.</p>
            <br>
            <a id="botao-head">Visit Website</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div id="content">
    <div class="content-box">
        <div class="content-box-img">
            <img src="img/logo-sysdevmss.png">
        </div>
        <div id="borderLeft"></div>
        <div class="content-box-text" id="sales" style="margin-top: 25px;">
            <p>Mobile sales System – Mobile application for Pre- Sales and Auto sales, distribution and tecnical services. Available to PDA and Tablet.<a class="more" href="sales" style="text-decoration: none;">[+]</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="content-box-link">
            <center><a id="botao-um">Visit Website</a></center>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-box">
        <div class="content-box-img">
            <img src="img/logo-sysdevkalipso.png">
        </div>
        <div id="borderLeft"></div>
        <div class="content-box-text" id="kalipso" style="margin-top: 25px;">
            <p>Kalipso is a fast and powerful mobile application generator for Microsoft OS (Mobile, CE, Seven, 8 PRO and Windows 10) and Android.<a class="more" href="kalipso" style="text-decoration: none;">[+]</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="content-box-link">
            <center><a id="botao-dois">Visit Website</a></center>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-box">
        <div class="content-box-img">
            <img src="img/logo-sysdevapps.png">
        </div>
        <div class="content-box-text" id="apps" style="margin-top: 25px;">
            <p>Sysdev is a company focused on developing mobile solutions in the techno-industry area.<a class="more" href="apps" style="text-decoration: none;">[+]</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="content-box-link">
            <center><a id="botao-tres">Visit Website</a></center>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="message-box" style="background-image: url('img/banner-sobre.jpg')">
        <div class="msg-links">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="sobre" id="sobre-link">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="visao" id="visao-link">Vision</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="missao" id="missao-link">Mission</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="valores" id="valores-link">Values</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <section id="content-msg">
            <div id="sobre">
                <div class="msg-header">
                    <h1>ABOUT <strong style="color:#00a6d4;">SYSDEV</strong></h1>
                </div>
                <style>
                    #sobre-link{
                        color:#00a6d4;
                    }
                </style>
                <div class="msg-content">
                    <p>It's a software company specialized in the development of mobility solutions in the techno-industrial area.</p>
                    <p>With an expert software development and programming team, Sysdev works constantly to provide integrated solutions, improving the process and effectiveness of all mobile solutions used by companies which in turn increases their profitability and efficiency.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <footer>
        <div id="footer-info">
            <div class="info">
                <center><img id="address" src="img/address.png"><h3>Address</h3></center>
                <p>Rua Dom Manuel Barbuda e Vasconcelos N31/33</p>
                <p>Urbanização Glicínias</p>
                <p>3810-498 AVEIRO, Portugal</p>
            </div>
            <div id="contact" class="info">
                <center><img id="phone" src="img/phone.png"><h3>Contacts</h3></center>
                <p>Main Line: +351 234 188 027</p>
                <p>Sales Line: +351 234 024 457</p>
                <p>Support Line: +351 234 098 189</p>
                <p>Fax: +351 234 188 400</p>
            </div>
            <div class="info">
                <center><img id="mail" src="img/mail.png"><h3>Emails</h3></center>
                <p>Sales: <a href="mailto:sales@sysdevmobile.com">sales@sysdevmobile.com</a></p>
                <p>Support: <a href="mailto:support@sysdevmobile.com">support@sysdevmobile.com</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer-links">
            <div id="sysdev" class="links">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="https://sysdevmss.com/pt">SYSDEV MSS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://sysdevkalipso.com/en">SYSDEV KALIPSO</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://sysdevapps.com/pt">SYSDEV APPS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="mailto:sales@sysdevmobile.com">CONTACT US</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="social" class="links">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/SysdevMobile/"><img src="img/facebook.jpg"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/MrktSysdev"><img src="img/youtube.jpg"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/811286?trk=tyah&trkInfo=tarId%3A1413147327921%2Ctas%3Asysdev%2Cidx%3A2-1-4"><img src="img/linkedin.jpg"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://twitter.com/Sysdevmobile"><img src="img/twitter.jpg"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="rights" class="links">
                <ul>
                    <li style="margin-right: 10px;">@ 2017 SYSDEV</li>
                    <li>POWERED BY</li>
                    <li><img src="img/logo-goweb.png"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.msg-links ul li a').click(function(){
            $('#content-msg').load('messages_en.phtml #' + $(this).attr('href'));
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.more').click(function(){
            $('#'+$(this).attr('href')).load('content-box_en.phtml #' + $(this).attr('href')+'-p');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.reset').click(function(){
            $('#'+$(this).attr('href')).load('reset_en.phtml #' + $(this).attr('href')+'-p');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: algum html para que possamos fazer teste?

Comment: Já actualizei a pergunta. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Os paragrafos encontram-se na div "content-box-text"

Comment: Consegui arranjar maneira de forçar a ler a script via o atributo "onclick" do link. Mas ele faz com que tenha de dar refresh a pagina que torna esta solução inutil.